# JSF inputSecret cannot access to char typed property

Tags: arrays, jsf, passwords

I want to submit following form via ajax. But when I submit it, it not get/ set value to char typed property. but when I changed password property in managed bean type as String it works. Why is that?

**Form**

```
<h:form>

        <h:inputText value="#{login.username}" id="username"
            a:placeholder="Username" />
        <br />

        <h:inputSecret a:placeholder="Password" id="password"
            value="#{login.password}" />
        <br />

        <h:inputText value="#{login.mvc}" />

        <h:commandButton value="Submit" >

            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="out" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:outputText id="out" />
    </h:form>
```

**Managed Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
public class Login {

    private String username;

    private char[] password;

    private String msg;

    private String mvc;

    @EJB
    private LoginService ls;

    public Login() {


    }



    public String getMvc() {
        return mvc;
    }



    public void setMvc(String mvc) {
        this.mvc = mvc;
    }



    public String getUsername() {
        System.out.println("getuser");
        return username;
    }



    public void setUsername(String username) {
        System.out.println("setuser");
        this.username = username;
    }

    public char[] getPassword() {
        System.out.println("getpass");

        return password;
    }



    public void setPassword(char[] password) {
        System.out.println("setpass");
        this.password = password;
    }



    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }


}
```

No console log error shows and. when the data type password is String, console shows `getuser` `setuser` `getpass` `setpass`. When the data type is char it shows `getuser` `getpass` Why is that? `char[]` is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on this [link](http://www.developersbook.com/jsf/jsf-tags-reference/html/inputSecret.php) it clearly mentioned

- Attribute Name :- value
- Description :- The value attribute sets the current value for this component.
- Type :-  String

For more and detailed information you can check SO question related to `<h:inputSecret />`

[Security: is there a way to use a straight reference to char[] instead of a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947689/hinputsecret-security-is-there-a-way-to-use-a-straight-reference-to-char)

Comment: So what can I do to convert it to char[] as secure way?

Comment: @top11 Why u r thinking String is not secure